# Interface upside-down on temporary lock orientation

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with Android 2.2 and screen
orientation. I have checkbox on my interface that when checked, the
orientation must be locked on the current orientation, so I did the
following code:

```
Activity a = (Activity) getContext();

if (isChecked) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} else {
    a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}
```

The problem with this is that if I turn upside down the device, my
screen will rotate to that, and when I click on my "lock orientation",
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation will return
SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT and my code will lock the orientation to
SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT and the interface will be upside-down.

I can see that on Gingerbread (http://developer.android.com/reference/
android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation), there is a reversePortait and
reverseLandscape to solve this, but I really need this code to run on
2.2, so is there anyway to set the screen to upside down? Or is there
any other way to lock the rotation?

Comment: Have you fixed this? I have a solution that works a bit better than yours here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599770/screen-orientation-lock

It's still not fully functional for Honeycomb as portrait gets reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScreenRotation.
ScreenOrientation is deprecated and does not know about upside-down portrait orientation.

Comment: Can you post a code example or point to the doc for this? I don't see any constants for rotation.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getOrientation%28%29

Comment: Display.getOrientation ()
Since: API Level 1

This method is deprecated.
use getRotation()

Comment: ScreenRotation is bad because some devices have "natural orientation" to landscape, while others have portrait, so while ROTATION_90 is landscape on a Galaxy Tab, it will be portrait on a Xoom.

Comment: Yes, you have to check the natural orientation too to use rotation as the device-manufacturer defines what the natural rotation 0° is for his device. This may help: http://softteco.blogspot.com/2011/08/universal-way-to-detect-landscape-mode.html